# UITableView Custom Cell not refreshing

Tags: ios, uitableview

There are a lot of questions about refreshing custom table cells but this one is an odd one. I have a tableView with each cell having, for now, a custom `UILabel` and `UIImageView`.

There are currently only 2 cells. The first one displays a date. When the table first loads, it displays the current date as a string in the first cells `UILabel`.

When I select the first cell,  I present a Custom Class which handles all the date picking. Once a date has been picked, this view is popped and I return back to the table view.

On `-(void)viewDidAppear` , the tableviews data is reloaded and the new selected date should appear.

However, the label in the first cell is not updated.

What confuses the matter is that if I have multiple cells all displaying the same data, these will all refresh and display the new date, as expected. It just seems that cell row at index: 0 will not refresh.

What further confuses the matter is that when I query the string value of the `UILabel` for the cell, it returns the correct date.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        // 
        // clears the grouped style border from each table cell
        //

        UIView *clearBgView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        [cell setBackgroundView:clearBgView];

        // label
        UILabel *dl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(70.0f, 10.0f, screenWidth-100, 50)];
        [self setDetailsLabel:dl];
        dl = nil;

        [[self detailsLabel] setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:.1 green:.1 blue:.1 alpha:.1  ]];
        [[self detailsLabel] setTextColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1.0f green:1.0f blue:1.0f alpha:.3f]];

        //icon for each cell
        UIImageView *ci = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(10.0f, 10.0f, 50.0f, 50.0f)];
        [ci setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:.2 green:.2 blue:.2 alpha:.2]];
        [self setCellIcon:ci];
        ci = nil;

        //
        // set up views
        //

        [cell addSubview:[self cellIcon]];
        [cell addSubview:[self detailsLabel]];
    }

    // Configure the cell...
    [cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];



    //populate each by row.
    NSString *dateDisplay = [self formatDate:[self dateCaught]];
    NSLog (@"date is %@", dateDisplay);
   [[self detailsLabel] setText:[self formatDate:[self dateCaught]]];

    switch (indexPath.row) { //this needs to be an integer, so return the row of the indexPath.
        case 0:
            NSLog (@"text for the cell is %@",[[self detailsLabel]text]);
            break;

        default:
            break;
    }


return cell;
```

}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem has to do with the way you pass the `detailsLabel` around. You keep it in a property or an ivar on `self`

```
[self setDetailsLabel:dl];
```

but you set it only when the cell is *not* available for reuse. When you reuse the cell, the `detailsLabel` on `self` is set to the label from the prior run, causing you all sorts of problems.

The cleanest solution is to create your own class deriving from `UITableViewCell`, move the initialization code that creates labels, icons, background colors, and so on into the designated initializer, and create properties for setting label texts. With this class in place, you would be able to simplify your code as follows:

```
UIMyCustomTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UIMyCustomTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
[[cell detailsLabel] setText:[self formatDate:[self dateCaught]]];
// ^--- detailsLabel can be moved to UIMyCustomTableViewCell now
```

Comment: Thanks for that last update, thats exactly what I am going to do. I was trying to hack it a bit by trying to customise the cell contents quickly like I was doing, but as you saw, ran into problems.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is, to not use a member variable like `@property detailsLabel`, but instead tags for all custom subviews. Change your code like this:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        if (cell == nil) {
            [...]

            // label
            UILabel *dl = [[UILabel alloc]initWithFrame:...];
            dl.tag = 99;
            [cell.contentView addSubview: dl];

            [...]
        }

        [...]

       UILabel *dl = [cell.contentView viewWithTag: 99];
       [dl setText:[self formatDate:[self dateCaught]]];

       [...]
       return cell;
}
```